# jQuery addClass function issues

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have one simple jQuery function, that does not work. I need to write a function that if anyone click on some class called 'modal-opened' it need to add class to body 'modal-open'. So i write function like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".modal-opened").click(function(){
        $("body").addClass("modal-open");
    });
});
```

I have that same function in JavaScript that works actually, here it is.

```
document.getElementById("modal-opened").addEventListener("click", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
    $("body").addClass("modal-open");
}
```

I need that same but in jQuery.

Comment: Sorry for that question. I realized that i write .modal-opened but it is #modal-opened.

Comment: As `modal-opened` is ID of element, prefix `#` for ID selector i.e. `$("#modal-opened").click(..............)`

Answer (score 0):

Notice you get modal-opened by ID in plain JS:

```js
// You get modal-opened by ID in plain JS
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#modal-opened").click(function(){
        $("body").addClass("modal-open");
    });
});
```

Comment: Question where the problem is a `simple typographical error` should be voted as closed, rather than answering them, since they are off-topic on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

try to do this:

```
<script>
    $(document).on('click','.modal-opened',function(){ 
       $("body").addClass("modal-open");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Delegated event is not the solution here, the problem is that the op has a type error in hes code

Answer (score -1):

There is an error in your jQuery code with reference to working javascript code you shared.

document.getElementById("modal-opened") in javascript is equivalent to **$("#modal-opened")** and not $(".modal-opened").

In jQuery, you can access an element by Id using # and by class using dot.

Hope this helps..
Please share your feedback.

Comment: The problem has already been pointed out multiple times, so added more answer with basic the same solution is not useful and might end up confusing other users.

Comment: @Carsten - I was preparing answer same time someone posting hence your comment in other answer did not come into my notion and I shared my answer. I think this action does not deserve down vote. If my answer is not proper then definitely you can.